# How do I Open the Red-Locked Doors?

Tags: dustforce

If you climb to the very top of Dustforce's hub world, you find a row of locked doors, and a scientist with the following message:

> I wouldn't go in there if I were you.

[image: I wouldn't go in there if I were you.]

How do I open these doors?  I don't want to know what's behind them, so please don't post it in your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get a SS on a gold door level to get a red key.

An SS on a silver door gets you a gold key.

Spoiler withheld by request, but iirc there are 16 red door locks here ;)

Comment: Some post in some random forum http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2489704 As @Stephen said, you need SS on a gold level to get your first red key