# Where are the Red-Locked Doors?

Tags: dustforce

I have 5 red keys in the game and I'd like to start opening the famous red locks. Problem is: I can't find them anywhere.

I've googling this, but all I've found out is that it's somewhere inside the laboratory. I feel like I'm the only one who can't find them!

**Where do I find the Red-Locked Doors?**

Comment: Some relevant information about [how to obtain red keys](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50512/how-do-i-open-the-red-locked-doors) for anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are at the top of the main Nexus, reachable by a wide vertical shaft between the tutorial and laboratory entrance.  The bottom of the shaft is quite high so reaching it can be a bit difficult with Dustman or Dustgirl, but if you can get 5 red keys that shouldn't be a problem for you.

The Dustforce subreddit (which you should check out as it's probably the most active community for the game) has a short [tutorial](http://dd.reddit.com/r/dustforce/comments/15w9kn/video_tutorial_climbing_up_the_chimney_to_the/) for reaching them.